# Why the dig (Domain Information Groper) use the Groper?

Tags: networking, dig

Why the dig (Domain Information Groper) use the Groper?

What' the Groper's meaning there?

I queried the dictionary, it is a person name or Epinephelussp.

Why in a Computer Terms the dig use the Groper?

Comment: I think this belongs on english.stackexchange, possibly with a note that "dig" refers to a computer program used to query domain names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its fairly simple - A groper is "someone who gropes".  To [grope](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/grope) means to "search blindly or uncertainly".

Its little more then a short cool (I assume) sounding acronym for a tool which helps search for a resource on the Internet.

Comment: It is the second sense that is used here - "to search for.."<domain information> not "to fondle"<domain information>